# Smart Playlist in iTunes for songs without ratings

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

Is there a way to create a Smart Playlist in iTunes that will show songs that aren’t rated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a playlist with a rule matching ratings with no stars.

[image: Playlist for unrated songs]

Comment: I missed the dragging all the way to the left, thanks!